# Apache .htaccess vs httpd - does it really matter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked many times and I've researched it myself on Google as well but just can't come up with the answer I need.

My hosting company is NOT letting me use the httpd config file, instead it wants me to use .htaccess.  I am not a server admin but I have to believe that there is a performance hit for using this file?  I have a site with approx 5 million page views a month and it's growing.  I do not have a lot of rewrite rules just some optimizations we make to serving pages faster ,mod_deflate, caching, etc.

Assuming there is a performance hit, my question is, how bad will it be on my site?  Can .htaccess handle 5 million page views with some rewrite rules?  How would I be able to test this if I wanted to?

Thanks.

Comment: 5 million page views per what time interval

Comment: Oops, 5 million page views per 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to my knowledge, the performance difference is negligible, compared to the computing time used for whatever's used in the `.htaccess`. For what's it's worth, I've seen no measurable difference by having a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Of couse, you'd have to set AllowOverrid to None to be able to see the difference.

Comment: How big a difference?  When does that "difference" start to matter?

Comment: Well, small enough that I haven't been able to measure the difference. That might not fly in a science paper, but I really don't think there's any performance gain here to speak of.

Answer (score 20):

**Yes**, it does matter. qouting from http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Htaccess:

> The use of .htaccess files is discouraged as they can have a
>   **detrimental** effect on server performance. Only use them when
>   necessary.

Answer (score 9):

With my test (based on: http://www.fubra.com/blog/2008/01/07/htaccess-vs-httpdconf/), the result is: **the performance difference is negligible**.

5000 rounds:

```
# htaccess Disabled
real    1m1.069s
user    0m10.956s
sys     0m9.748s

# htaccess Enabled
real    1m1.658s
user    0m11.434s
sys     0m9.848s
```

Answer (score 4):

Performance hit for reading the file? That's micro-optimization. Favour .htaccess. You don't need special privileges to edit it.

Also on a shared hosting site, everyone shares the httpd.conf settings so, if thats your situation, it's not applicable.

Comment: No, it's a dedicated server and my site is the only one on it.  After reading Apache optimization techniques, they all point to using httpd instead of htaccess but don't really provide stats to back it up.

Comment: if it's a dedicated server why can't you edit your httpd.conf that would really annoy me. Maybe you could get a import into the httpd.conf.