# How to use cache HTML, Apache or PHP

Tags: php, html, apache, caching, laravel

I am developing a web page, and all the webpage tests recommend me to use a cache system.
I've been researching and I have seen that there are three main ways.
One is to use Meta tags with the expire atribute.
Another is to use PHP headers.
And the other is to use the .htacces.

Is there any different between these options?
Which one do you recommend me? (By the way, I'm using Laravel).

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: This question may fit better on the [Webmaster's Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, mayby, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meta tags are not an effective way to specify cache control headers](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META), you need real HTTP headers.

The client has no way of telling how you generate your headers, so it doesn't matter if you use PHP or Apache directives. PHP is probably going to be easier for you for anything that uses PHP already, while Apache directives are the only way to deal with static files.

As usual, putting Apache directives in a load time configuration file will be [slightly more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10446650/19068) than using a runtime one (i.e. .htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question that has an exhaustive answer. Check out apache mod_cache for caching of content on apache. and along side if you are going the performance road also check out mod_deflate. A simple google with the mod names will give you enough matter to configure your apache version for them.